# How to run ansible playbooks from jenkins- Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a simple playbook to download a file from S3 as follows

```
---
  -  name: Download file
     s3: 
       profile: update
       region:  eu-west-2
       bucket: leases
       object: /{{item}}
       dest: /etc/downlds/{{ item }}
       mode: get    
     with_items: 
         - "{{ item1}}"
         - "{{ item2}}"

     register: downloads
     delegate_to: localhost 
     tags: download items
```

when i run the above playbook from console it works fine, in jenkins pipeline i have this

```
node {
    ansiblePlaybook installation: 'Ansible', playbook: '/home/ec2-user/Playbooks/copyfile.yml'
}
```

when i run the pipeline job i am getting an error like below

```
[tests] $ /usr/local/bin/ansible-playbook /home/ec2-user/Playbooks/copyfile.yml
FATAL: command execution failed
java.io.IOException: Process working directory '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/tests' doesn't exist!
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:247)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:218)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:930)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:450)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.join(Launcher.java:461)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ansible.CLIRunner.execute(CLIRunner.java:49)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ansible.AbstractAnsibleInvocation.execute(AbstractAnsibleInvocation.java:290)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ansible.AnsiblePlaybookInvocation.execute(AnsiblePlaybookInvocation.java:31)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ansible.AnsiblePlaybookBuilder.perform(AnsiblePlaybookBuilder.java:261)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ansible.workflow.AnsiblePlaybookStep$AnsiblePlaybookExecution.run(AnsiblePlaybookStep.java:400)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ansible.workflow.AnsiblePlaybookStep$AnsiblePlaybookExecution.run(AnsiblePlaybookStep.java:321)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:260)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:44)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I use jenkins ansible plugin for this, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you using different nodes to run the build?

Comment: Yes, master is in linux and slave is in windows